# Architecture for distributed workers

Tags: node.js, redis, rabbitmq

We are creating a website able to distribute tasks across multiple geographical sites.
The website should be able to:

- create a task,
- put it in a queue,
- assign it to a worker depending on a geographical criteria,
- update the web interface according to the working status (step 1, 2 3 etc.),
- save the final result in mongodb and notice the web interface.

We can have parallel jobs working as long as they are not in the same geographical criteria.

We can delete a job as long as it is not in processing state.

Our current stack is: Angulajs - nodejs - mongodb.

Our first idea was to make an HTTP pooling from the distant workers to the mongodb task. The point is that we will have more than 20 distant workers and we would like a high frequency refresh (< 1s). We think that this solution is easy to implement but will be difficult to maintain and make overload of the DB. This solution is highly dependent to the network ping.

After some researchs on the web, we found documentation on rabbitMQ and message system. This seems to fit most of our requirements but I don’t see how we can delete a specific job in a queue in pending state and how we can easily handle the update of the task status.

We found also documentation about redis, a KV system in RAM. This solves the issue to be able to delete a specific task in a queue and reduce mongodb load but we don’t see how we will be able to notice distant worker on the job to do. If it is HTTP pooling, we lost all the benefits.

Our situation seems to be a usual problem I and would like to know what the best solution is?

Comment: Redis has pub/sub where you can subscribe your workers and they will be notified when there is work there. But any pub/sub solution would only scale and perform well in LANs... if you need a WAN solution you could look into Shovel or something like that to replicate your brokers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So if my understanding is good redis pub/sub is not adapted for WAN. I will have to use RabbitMQ with shovel. Regarding the deletion of a specific task in a queue, I had the suggestion to add an admin queue per worker in which I can send message like 'IGNORE TASK #111'. This solution seems to work but is-it a relevant solution?

Comment: You cant guarantee that the admin message will reach consumers before the task is actually executed. RabbitMQ won't help you on this case. You are better off replicating the KV store (like Redis) across WAN if you want to control your queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The architecture is interesting, and I think you can use RabbitMQ.

> 1.“create a task”

you can create an AMQP message

> 2.“put it in a queue”

you can put it to an Queue or maybe better to an Exchange

> 3.assign it to a worker depending on a geographical criteria:

you can use the shovel plug-in and assign the task using the routing-key. The plug-in is design to tolerate slow and geographical networks.

> 4.update the web interface according to the working status (step 1, 2 3 etc.)

This it's easy, you can redirect the message to the web-page using the web-socket, or you can enable the JavaScript web-STOMP plug-in “rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp”, and use it directly to update the page.

> 5.save the final result in mongodb and notice the web interface:

Once gets the message you can save it to the database.

The only things just a bit hard it's delete an message, you could get the messages without the ack, then send the ack to the message you want delete. 
Anyway this is not a right way to use RabbitMQ, I don't know exactly your environment, but you could considerer to use the expire message via TTL message (http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html).

In order to update a task, you shouldn't update the message to the queue, but send another message with the “update” information, then your application should update the task status for example in your internal list.

I hope it can be useful.

Comment: Thank you, but how will I be able to display the working status on the web page as I don't have access to the queue content? Should I write a special consumer that consume and reinject all the content in the queue or should I have a special collection in mongodb that will be updated ?

Comment: The second one. 
I never use it, but you could considerer also www.celeryproject.org

Comment: After a long reflection on this topic, we will use the RabbitMQ solution

Answer (score 11):

### Redis

Redis is great because you can use it for other features besides Job Queuing, like caching. I personally use [Kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue). Kueing jobs across datacenters might not be the best decision. Though I don't understand your circumstance, it's generally accepted that your data model be centralized where as your content be distributed. I run a service that hosts an API in San Fransisco, and has CDN nodes in San Fran and NYC. My content is server side templates, images, scripts, css, etc. Which can be completely populated by my API.

### Outsource

If you absolutely need this functionality I would personally recommend [iron.io](http://www.iron.io/). They offer 2 services that may be able to solve your problem. Firstly they offer an MQ system through a RESTful API, which is very easy to use and works perfectly with node. The also offer a Worker service, which allows you to queue, schedule, and run tasks on their stack. This would be limiting if you needed to access resources from your own cloud, in which case I would recommend ironMQ.

### Insource

If you don't want to outsource your service, and you want to host an MQ I would not recommend rabbitMQ for job queuing. I'd recommend something like [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) which is more geared towards *job queuing*, where as RabbitMQ is more geared towards **message queuing**(who'd thunk?).

### Additionally:

Having read some of the comments to some of the other answers it seems to me that beanstalkd might be your best approach. It's more specific to job queuing, whereas many other MQ systems are to message about updates and push new data across your cloud in realtime and you'll have to implement your own Job Queuing system on top of that.

Comment: Thank you, I need to study beanstalkd closely. Seems interesting.

Comment: As someone else had mentioned SQS is a good option, but it's ultimately an outsourced solution.

Comment: To be quite honest, all these queuing services are really meant to be `inbound`. Redis might actually be one of the better outbound solutions simple because [it offers more security features](http://redis.io/topics/security). I still wouldn't deem this good practice. You should really consider _not distributing your cluster geographically_. Can you explain why this must be done? You should really keep your API in _one_ location, and distribute your content through a CDN.

Comment: Maybe the approch is not good. We are working on a central web server that is able to distribute tests accross multiple geographical sites. We have some probes that need to do this work asynchronously. The probe must launch a job maximum 1 second after the action request from the webserver. We need to communicate between the webserver and the probe over the net. Our first prototype is using HTTP pooling from the probe to the web central server but I was wondering if a queue message system can improve the architecture and ease the maintenance.

Comment: @Julio I think you're looking for something that's much more specific to your needs than a Job Queue or a Message Queue. It would be very difficult and sloppy to discuss this through comments. If you could create a new question and perhaps comment a link to this question. I would be more than happy to give you a more extensive answer specific to the technology you're trying to implement.

Comment: @tsturzl I found many people reported issues on Kue, you can refer here https://github.com/Automattic/kue/issues/130 did you use it in production? if so, what is your experience? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Rabbit MQ, Redis and ZeroMQ are awesome but you can do it without leave mongoDB. There are special collections named [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) that allow streaming and they are both extremely fast and cheap to work it for your database. You can have your workers (or another process) listening the queue and then doing the tasks.

For example, imagine that you have a worker for every region and said regions are tagged with strings. Then we just need to create a internal queue to handle the updates in your main logic. We will use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) and [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to show it:

```
var internalQueue = async.queue(function (doc, callback) {
    doc.status = 2; 
    doc.save(function(e){ // We update the status of the task
        // And we follow from here, doing whatever we want to do
    })
}, 1);



mongoose
.TaskModel
.find({
    status: 1,
    region: "KH" // Unstarted stuff from Camboya
})
.stream()
.on('data', function (doc){
    internalQueue.push(doc, function(e){
        console.log('We have finished our task, alert the web interface or save me or something');
    });
});
```

Maybe you don't want to use mongoose, or async, or want to use [geoqueries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) or more than one worker per region but you can do it with the tools you already have: mongoDB and Node.js

To start working around with capped collections just use [createCollection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection) on mongoDB terminal:

```
db.createCollection('test', {capped: true, size: 100*1000, max: 100} )
```

Just remember two things:

1. Data will expire based on insert order not time or last access to that document so do your collections big enough.
2. You can't remove a document, but you can simply empty it

Comment: Thank you. For your solution, the worker will have to be on a the same LAN as the DB. We will have to pull on the `TaskModel` capped collection, isn't it?

Comment: I think you don't need to be in the same LAN as the DB. I have done it with [mongolab](https://mongolab.com/welcome/) for example. If the worker can connect with mongoDB it can stream from the capped collection.

Comment: Yes, the `TaskModel` is supposed to be the model from where you pull the information.

Answer (score 2):

Were I work we are using [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) and I can very much recommend it to you.
It's cheap, reliable, scales and saves you a lot of trouble (maintaining the queue system). We have workers in various Amazon regions across the globe.

For node there is `aws-sdk`, look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html) for the documentation

Comment: Thank you but we can't depend on Amazon and we need to be able to run it on private global network

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've also have positive experience with Kafka. https://kafka.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to give useful advice given the scope of your question.  But, if it were me, I'd probably use [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall), I'd use some variation like Router-Req, I'd maintain the queue and all data related to the work on the server and just deal the tasks I was ready to deal to workers who are ready to work, with the understanding that they will begin work immediately on a task as they receive it and the only data I need to feed back to the server is completed work.  If you need the ability to abort work-in-progress, you can use a second pair of sockets for control communications, probably a Req-Rep pairing.

The socket patterns are described in full in the linked guide, and it will do a much better job of describing them than I can usefully here, though it's a major read.

Answer (score 0):

The module https://github.com/jkyberneees/distributed-eventemitter make distributed messaging super simple by re-using the EventEmitter API and STOMP brokers.
For sure it will help you a lot on your messaging architecture.